# Turning warning into errors in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to turn warnings into errors in Jupyter notebook running a Python 3 kernel using:

```
from warnings import warn, simplefilter
simplefilter('error')
```

While this works when using Python from the command line, this makes Jupyter crash. Has anyone run into this issue before? Would anyone know of a fix?

Thank you

Comment: Crashes for me too, have you find solution OP?

Answer (score 0):

To turn all warnings into errors you need to do:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')
```

Please refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html for more options

```
default                      # Show all warnings (even those ignored by default)
ignore                       # Ignore all warnings
error                        # Convert all warnings to errors
error::ResourceWarning       # Treat ResourceWarning messages as errors
default::DeprecationWarning  # Show DeprecationWarning messages
ignore,default:::mymodule    # Only report warnings triggered by "mymodule"
error:::mymodule[.*]         # Convert warnings to errors in "mymodule"
                             # and any subpackages of "mymodule"
```